# Break the current program without exiting VIM

Tags: shell, vim

When using VIM, I usually like to run programs by using the bang in command mode.
That is, use

```
:!<external shell command>
```

to test code without exiting vim or alt-tabbing to another open shell. So for example, when writing Java code, I might do something like

```
:!java Main
```

Or in C, maybe

```
:!cls & gcc -g -o main Program.c File.c & main
```

This works fine. The VIM window turns into a shell, my program runs, and then upon exit I get back into VIM.

The issue is when my program hits an infinite loop. I get stuck with the terminal displaying the standard output and then I can't get back to VIM. Control-C exits EVERYTHING and then I need to re-open VIM and re-open all my files and it's a big mess (especially if I didn't save something!).

tl;dr Is there a way to stop internally-running externally-defined shell commands in VIM?

Comment: I don't know who commented what or if it got deleted, but somehow I read try Ctrl-z works. And it does! :D So I posted an answer about it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Control-z works instead of Control-c

Answer (score 3):

In my case, `Ctrl-c` works just fine.

I am on `vim 7.4` on ubuntu 14.04.